# Spring @InitBinder not invoked when showing form => CustomEditors not defined

Tags: binding, spring-mvc, annotations, propertyeditor

I have following (simplified to the bone) Controller:

```
@Controller  
public class TestController  {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(final ModelMap map) {
    final TestFilter filter = new TestFilter();
    filter.setStartDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    map.addAttribute("reportPerResourceForm", filter);
    return "test";
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, null, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"), true));
}
```

}

The jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="reportPerResourceForm" id="reportForm">
    <form:input path="startDate" />
</form:form>
```

This is a controller I quickly created to test out an issue I had with another view-controller. As you can see in the Controller a CustomeDateEditor is defined. In my actual controller this editor is working fine; when you enter for instance 11/01/2010 in the form field this is nicely converted into a Date by the editor; also when going back to the form the Date was again nicely converted back to a String.

However, when I (as in TestController) want to set a default date on the form then this gets simply displayed a Date.toString() in the form field instead of using the returned value from CustomDateEditor.getAsText()! After some debugging I learned that my InitBinder method is not called when RequestMethod == GET. Is this normal?

I'm sure I could workaround this by not using

Thanks for your help,
Stijn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `@ModelAttribute` to setup domain before forwarding to page.

carefully to use `new` when you deal with spring, it will just create a new instance of object outside spring context and you cannot use any of spring capability (such as web binding, validation, etc).

example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute yourDomain, final ModelMap map)
```

and at your domain you can use :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date balance = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but the second argument in registerCustomEditor method is set to null. This argument is to set the field name you want to associate the editor with, so I don't know exactly what it is going to happen when it's set to null. If you want to use this editor with all fields of a specific type it exists the same method without this parameter:

```
public void registerCustomEditor(Class requiredType, PropertyEditor propertyEditor)
```

I would try with this, though I'm not sure this will solve the problem.

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"), true));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Javi; tx but actualy I added the null parameter just 'to have tried anything'. Calling registerCustomEditor without this parameter boils down to the same thing (eventualy it calls registerCustomEditor with null as field).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I myself have following code in my Controller:

```
        @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Category.class, new CategoryEditor(categoryService));
        }

        @ModelAttribute("categoryList") // Populate reference-data (EG select-lists) in the view. (p. 390-

    391).
        public List<Category> populateCategoryList() {
            return categoryService.list();
        }

        // Note: without adding "BindingResult result" to the following prototype
        // (and preceding it with a @ModelAttribute("categoryList") -
        // my initBibder() method does not get called!
        // I discovered and added this hokum in response to the following links:
        // http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?46837-InitBinder-not-called
        // http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?46876-Custom-date-format-on-GET-requests&p=154820
        @RequestMapping("/site/list.htm")
        @ModelAttribute("sites")  // 20110819
        public ModelAndView listSite(
                @ModelAttribute("category") Category category,
                BindingResult result
                )
        {
    //        List<Site> sites = siteService.list();
            List<Site> sites = new ArrayList<Site>(); // = siteService.list();
            return new ModelAndView("siteList", "sites", sites);
        }
    }
```

My issues was with my "Category" class not being recognized, because @InitBinder was not being called.
The "secret" here was to modify my "@RequestMapping" method to include - in it's prototype - 2 parameters 

which I do not need: 

            @ModelAttribute("category") Category category,


            BindingResult result


This solved everything (I know it's not magic, just smoke, mirrors and Java reflection - but I wish the 

printed and online literature would address simple use-cases like this appropriately).

Here's the relevant code in my corresponding JSP file:

```
        <div>
        Select a category: 
        <form:select path="category">
                    <form:options items="${categoryList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" 

    />
        </form:select>
        </div>
```