# spring mvc @InitBinder is not called when processing ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    this.binder = binder;
}
```

when processing the normal request , the function can be called , but if the first request is an ajax request

```
@RequestMapping("create")
@ResponseBody
public String create(@RequestBody String body) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    try{
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject(body);
        T t = buildEntity(params);
        service().save(t);
        result.put(ExtConstant.DATA, t.detailJson());
        result.put(ExtConstant.SUCCESS, true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        result.put(ExtConstant.SUCCESS, false);
        result.put(ExtConstant.ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

the function initBinder is not been called , the binder is null . that really confuse me

Comment: Try using `@ModelAttribute` instead as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638848/spring-initbinder-not-invoked-when-showing-form-customeditors-not-defined

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the correct behavior - `@InitBinder` annotated methods are only called when arguments that need binding are being resolved, so in your case if you had a `@RequestMapping`/`@ModelAttribute` method with arguments like your command/model object which require binding then `@InitBinder` will be called.

In this specific case your `create` method has an argument body which is annotated with `@RequestBody`, this argument is not resolved by the binder but the MessageConverters(from json/xml to the appropriate type), and so the `@InitBinder` method is not called.

Comment: I have the problem as described here. I need to process my RequestBody with an InitBinder to escape possible scripts in my input data. Any ideas how to solve this?