# @InitBinder with @RequestBody escaping XSS in Spring 3.2.4

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am having a `@RequestBody` annotated argument in my method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/courses/{courseId}/{name}/comment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody CommentContainer addComment(@PathVariable Long courseId,
                          @ActiveAccount Account currentUser,
                          @Valid @RequestBody AddCommentForm form,
                          BindingResult formBinding,
                          HttpServletRequest request) throws RequestValidationException {

.....
}
```

Then I have a `@InitBinder` annotated method in the same controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(AddCommentForm.class, new StringEscapeEditor());
}
```

My `StringEscapeEditor` is not running. But my `initBinder` method is. So it does not mapping my form to the escape editor. This seems right after reading this thread (Where it seems like `@RequestMapping` is not supported by `@InitBinder`):

[spring mvc @InitBinder is not called when processing ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486512/spring-mvc-initbinder-is-not-called-when-processing-ajax-request)

And i tested to map a `@PathVariable` string and then my editor is working.

This is a big deal in my application since most of my bindings is done with `@RequestBody` and it would be great if i could apply some custom bindings to it.

What is the most common way to solve this problem? and to escape my input data for script attacks.

Comment: `@InitBinder` doesn't work with `@RequestBody`. The binder is used when doing data binding with `@ModelAttribute`. `@RequestBody` is parsed by Jackons or XML parser or ... depending on the requested type. If you want custom binding configure jackson.

Comment: Okey, thank you for confirming that. I guess I could throw `@RequestBody` in the trash and start sending `@ModelAttribute` through my ajax calls?

Comment: No... `@ModelAttribute` works with binding request parameters not with a request body.

Comment: I would suggest escaping when outputting data rather than on input because escape method differs depending on the document type you're outputting (e.g. it's different for html and for, for example, csv). If you really want to do it on input and using `@ResponseBody` then look into configuring Jackson to it.

Comment: @M.Deinum What I mean was that I could remove `@RequestBody AddCommentForm form` and instead map something like `@ModelAttribute("addCommentForm") AddCommentForm form` and then I could use an initbinder with some custom mappings.

Comment: @KresimirNesek The reason I like to do it there is that I am directly sending the finished comment back to the client and printing it on the view. Populating the page with a handlebars template, where I can't use any JSP tags to escape the data.

Comment: No as you are using ajax with a request body and that doesn't work with `@ModelAttribute`. If you want custom binding modify the binding mechanism and in yuor case that is Jackson, just configure the `ObjectMapper`. `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` are for different things.

Comment: @nilsi In that case you can customize Jackson's string escaping when serializing objects so strings in JSON generated by `@ResponseBody` would be html escaped. I have used this approach and it's a bit complicated if you want to only optionally turn on escaping. Will post an answer a bit later.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes but I would change my forms to spring forms and mapping my model attribute so I could catch it in my controller. But that would might cause other problem and doesn't seems to be worth it. I could also in my forms use `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(string)` on all strings (On the server side). Not a very pretty solution though and I might miss some places.

Comment: @KresimirNesek Yes if you want to show how to customize Jackson it would be great. Since it seems to be the way to go here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To escape XSS I suggest that escaping is done while outputting the data, because correct escaping depends on the output document.

If JSON response generated by `@ResponseBody` is consumed directly by the client and there is no opportunity to XSS escape the content, then JacksonMessageConverter can be customised to perform XSS escaping on strings.

One can customise JacksonMessageConverter like this:

1) First we create ObjectMapper factory that will create our custom object mapper:

```
public class HtmlEscapingObjectMapperFactory implements FactoryBean<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public HtmlEscapingObjectMapperFactory() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.getJsonFactory().setCharacterEscapes(new HTMLCharacterEscapes());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getObject() throws Exception {
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ObjectMapper.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    public static class HTMLCharacterEscapes extends CharacterEscapes {

        private final int[] asciiEscapes;

        public HTMLCharacterEscapes() {
            // start with set of characters known to require escaping (double-quote, backslash etc)
            asciiEscapes = CharacterEscapes.standardAsciiEscapesForJSON();
            // and force escaping of a few others:
            asciiEscapes['<'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            asciiEscapes['>'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            asciiEscapes['&'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            asciiEscapes['"'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
            asciiEscapes['\''] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_CUSTOM;
        }


        @Override
        public int[] getEscapeCodesForAscii() {
            return asciiEscapes;
        }

        // and this for others; we don't need anything special here
        @Override
        public SerializableString getEscapeSequence(int ch) {
            return new SerializedString(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(Character.toString((char) ch)));

        }
    }
}
```

(inspiration for HtmlCharacterEscapes came from this question: [HTML escape with Spring MVC and Jackson Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133811/html-escape-with-spring-mvc-and-jackson-mapper))

2) Then we register the message converter that uses our custom object mapper (example in xml config):

```
<bean id="htmlEscapingObjectMapper" class="com.example.HtmlEscapingObjectMapperFactory" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" p:objectMapper-ref="htmlEscapingObjectMapper" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Now all the JSON messages created by `@ResponseBody` should have strings escaped as specified in HTMLCharacterEscapes.

Alternative solutions to the problem:

- XSS escape what you need in the controller body after the objects have been deserialised
- maybe XSS escape in javascript on the client before outputting the content

In addition to doing output escaping, it may be useful to also do some input validation (using standard Spring validation methods) to block some of the content that you don't want to be entered into the system / database.

**EDIT: JavaConfig**

I haven't tried this out but in Java config it should work like this (you won't need Factory Bean from above because you can set up everything in config in this case):

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(buildHtmlEscapingJsonConverter());

}

private MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter buildHtmlEscapingJsonConverter() {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter htmlEscapingConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.getJsonFactory().setCharacterEscapes(new HTMLCharacterEscapes());
    htmlEscapingConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return htmlEscapingConverter;       
}
```

Please be aware that any other non-json default message converters that would normally be configured will now be lost (e.g. XML converters etc..) and if you need them, you will need to add them manually (you can see what's active by default here in section 2.2: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)

Comment: Do you know how to configure this in Java WebMvcConfig? Having problem getting it right. I can do `@Override public void configureMessageConverters( List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters ) { converters.add(CONVERTER_GOES_HERE);}` in the java mvc config but not sure how to define the converter

Comment: Edited to include guidelines for java config.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter? Any alternatives?

Comment: For future visitors: Use Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

Comment: How i can escape html in json printing in JSP?

Comment: The default message converters are lost only when using Spring and using a WebMvcConfigurer implementation. When using Spring Boot, that is not the case. Just define a HttpMessageConverter<T> bean. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest for more information.