# How to pass input parameters to spring ReST web service avoiding SQL injection

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, sql-injection

I'm creating an spring ReST application & passing input paramaters to the service using "WizTools.Org RestClient 3.2.2" as follows

```
{
"user_id": 23,
"user_email_id": "a@a.com",
"user_password": "fdsdsdf",
"firstname": "select * from user where  user_email_id =  'anything' OR 'x'='x'",
"lastname": "sadffsd",
"mobile_number": "1414141414",
"user_status": 1,
"isdeleted": 0,
"created_by": 1,
"profile_picturename": "kfksdjfhksjd",
"address": "sfdsdfsd"
```

}

Here for first name i want to make sure that any SQL injection should not get injected along with my input parameters to provide safety to the user. Can anybudy suggest me any good suggestion for same

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear. Add the full stacktrace of your tomcat startup.

Comment: @Jah, updated question, plz check first name field in input parameters & how can i avoid such kind of user inputs

Comment: #is your question really related tp : "my tomcat server is not getting started & showing Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start." ? If so, add the full stacktrace

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403676/initbinder-with-requestbody-escaping-xss-in-spring-3-2-4) is an interessting link.

Comment: @jah, Can you place answer for same, that really helped me, thank you