# Spring StringTrimmerEditor not trimming the whitespaces

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, bean-validation, spring-rest, spring-validator

I am creating a registration endpoint for my rest-api. For which, I need to use StringTrimmerEditor. My initBinder method gets called everytime. But blank spaces are still surpassing the endpoint.

I have the same code for other project and it works perfectly there, but not this time!

RestController-

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder){
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }
```

If for registration, i pass the json as:
{
  "username": " hey   " ,
  "password": " "
} which has whitespaces

It registers the same strings with equal number of white spaces

Answer (score 1):

Well, just got to know that @InitBinder doesn't work with @RequesBody, it can work with @Model Annotation. But if you want , you can customize the configuration as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405385/10014442).

Answer (score 0):

As of I Know StringTrimEditor will not remove spaces automatically, you have to give the character to delete.

```
StringTrimmerEditor(String charsToDelete, boolean emptyAsNull)
Create a new StringTrimmerEditor like this.
```

do the Changes as below it will work

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder){
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(" ", true));
    }
```